# Go obtain pointer to struct from interface?

Tags: go, go-interface

Given an interface, how do I obtain a pointer to the underlying value?

My naive attempt was to use a type assertion like this:

```
var mytypeptr *MyType = myinterface.(*MyType)
```

But I get:

```
interface conversion: MyInterface is MyType, not *MyType
```

Comment: I think you want to put `*MyType` in the `interface` int the first place here. Interface values internally contain pointers already for any type longer than a machine word; the compiler is smart enough to not make that a pointer-to-pointer when you store a `*MyType` ([here's gnarly test code to demonstrate](http://play.golang.org/p/3Y3QKTmSW8)); and `.` behaves the same for the pointer type as for the actual struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start with, using [`reflect.Indirect()`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Indirect):

```
val := reflect.ValueOf(myinterface)
if val.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
    val = reflect.Indirect(val)
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to modify struct fields behind an interface without resorting to using reflect?

Comment: @erjoalgo considering how an interface is structured (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/23148998/6309), no: at runtime, the interface masks the underlying value. Interfaces are statically typed (http://stackoverflow.com/a/23724093/6309)