# Why can't I use a pointer to a specific type where *interface{} is expected?

Tags: pointers, go, typechecking

I have the following function:

```
func bytesToData(data interface{}, b []byte) error {
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(b)
    dec := gob.NewDecoder(buf)
    return dec.Decode(data)
}
```

I use this for getting struct data in and out of boltdb. What I'd like to do, is change that signature to:

```
func bytesToData(data *interface{}, b []byte) error
```

And then I'd like to be able to call it like this (`b` in this case is a gob-encoded `Account`)

```
acc := &Account{}
err := bytesToData(acc, b)
```

But when I do that, I get an error like `Cannot use *Account for type *interface{}`.

For now, I've just changed it back to `interface{}`. But then, if I pass in an `Account` or some other type directly without making it a pointer, gob throws an error. It seems like this should be checkable at compile time. And given that an argument of type `interface{}` accepts anything, why doesn't an argument of type `*interface{}` accept a pointer to anything?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The genericity of interface types in Go is not passed on to derived types. This applies to pointers (as you noticed), and also to slices, channels, etc. For example, you can't assign a `[]string` to a `[]interface{}`.

There are various ways to explain this. For a Haskell programmer:

Go does not have covariant or contravariant types. All type constructors (such as the `*` that creates a pointer type) are invariant. So even though `Account` and `*Account` (and all other types) are subtypes of `interface{}`, nothing is a subtype of `*interface{}` or `[]interface{}`. This is sometimes inconvenient, but it keeps Go's type system and assignability rules much simpler.

For a C programmer:

An `interface{}` can hold a value of any type, but it does not hold it directly. Rather than being a variable-sized magic container, it is just a struct consisting of a pointer to a type and a pointer to a value. When you assign a concrete type to an `interface{}`, both of these fields are filled in. `*interface{}` is a pointer to one of these structs. When you try to assign a `*Account` to a `*interface{}`, there is nowhere to put the type information, because the `*interface{}` is a single machine word that just holds a pointer. So the compiler won't let you do that.

Comment: Love the extremes of the Haskell / C contrast.

Answer (score 3):

`interface{}` could also contain a pointer with no problem.
But there is nothing like a pointer to `interface{}`

See these:

[Cast a struct pointer to interface pointer in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27178635/cast-a-struct-pointer-to-interface-pointer-in-golang)

[Why can't I assign a *Struct to an *Interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13511203/why-cant-i-assign-a-struct-to-an-interface)