# How to assign struct to interface

Tags: go

Here is my code:

```
type ICacheEngine interface {
   // ...
}

// implements all methods of ICacheEngine
type RedisCache struct { }

type ApplicationCache struct { 
  Cache *ICacheEngine
}

func NewRedisCache() *ApplicationCache {
    appCache := new(ApplicationCache)
    redisCache := new(RedisCache)
    appCache.Cache = redisCache   // here is an error : can not use *RedisCache as *ICacheEngine
    return appCache
}
```

`RedisCache` implements all methods of `ICacheEngine`. I can pass `RedisCache` to the method which get `ICacheEngine`:

```
func test(something ICacheEngine) *ICacheEngine {
    return &something
}

....

appCache.Cache = test(redisCache)
```

But I cannot assign `RedisCache` to `ICacheEngine`.  Why ? How can I avoid `test()` function ? And what will be looking programming with interfaces when I set concrete type to interface and next call it methods ?

Comment: First you are able to assign `redisCache` to `ICacheEngine` Because it is an interface. You can pass any type of argument to a function with interface parameter.

Comment: Two comments: Never use a pointer to an interface (this is _wrong_ in almost all the cases). Do not call an interface `I...` (this is neither C# nor Java).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Considering an interface can store a stuct *or* a pointer to a struct, make sure to define your ApplicationCache struct as:

```
type ApplicationCache struct { 
  Cache ICacheEngine
}
```

See "[Cast a struct pointer to interface pointer in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27178682/6309)".

Answer (score 0):

Here **clientStruct** is implementing the "**ClientInterface**".

And we assigning the struct to interface.

```
package restclient

import (
    "net/http"
)

type clientStruct struct{}

type ClientInterface interface {
    Get(string) (*http.Response, error)
}
// assigning the struct to interface
var (
    ClientStruct ClientInterface = &clientStruct{}
)

func (ci *clientStruct) Get(url string) (*http.Response, error) {
    request, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    client := http.Client{}

    return client.Do(request)
}
```