# Could a method return a pointer with return type of this method is value

Tags: go, pointers, return-value, return-type, go-interface

I saw a piece of code as below:

Just wondering as the **value method** of `draw()` have been implemented, why could it return the **pointer** of the struct in fact.

```
type Shape interface {
    draw()
}

type Rectangle struct {
}

func (Rectangle) draw() {
    fmt.Println("Draw Rectangle")
}

type Square struct {
}

func (Squre) draw() {
    fmt.Println("Draw Square")
}

type Circle struct {
}

func (Circle) draw() {
    fmt.Println("Draw Circle")
}


type ShapeFactory struct {
}

func (*ShapeFactory) CreateShape(shape string) Shape {
    if shape == "Rectangle" {
        return &Rectangle{}
    } else if shape == "Square" {
        return &Square{}
    } else if shape == "Circle" {
        return &Circle{}
    }
    return nil

}
```

I think should it be like below to implement a pointer method so that the method `CreateShape` could return the pointer of struct?

```
type Rectangle struct {
}

func (*Rectangle) draw() {
    fmt.Println("Draw Rectangle")
}
```

Comment: please refer this [interfaces](https://gobyexample.com/interfaces) example.

Comment: The `Shape` type is an *interface* type and not a struct type. The `*Rectangle`, `*Square`, and `*Circle` types implement the `Shape` interface, which is why they can be returned by that method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return type defined on the `CreateShape` method is not a struct but an interface. Therefore `CreateShape` can return any type as long as it implements the `Shape` interface.

Comment: hi, I have edited my question, i' d like to know why the code could work with just implementing value method but return the pointer?  Thanks anyway.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you return a pointer or a value as long as they conform to what is defined by the interface. Please also review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27178635/cast-a-struct-pointer-to-interface-pointer-in-golang.

Comment: @s666 See [method sets](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets), especially the following: *"The method set of any other type `T` consists of all methods declared with receiver type `T`. The method set of the corresponding pointer type `*T` is the set of all methods declared with receiver `*T` **or `T` (that is, it also contains the method set of `T`)**."*

Comment: @s666 but keep in mind that the reverse is *not* true, i.e. the methods declared with receiver `*T` are *not* part of the method set of `T`.