# Convert []string to []interface{}

Tags: go, type-conversion

I just want to write some code like this:

```
func (w Writer) WriteVString(strs []string) (int, error) {
    return writeV(func(index int, str interface{}) (int, error) {
        return w.WriteString(str.(string))
    }, strs) // it doesn't work
}

func (w Writer) WriteV(bs [][]byte) (int, error) {
    return writeV(func(index int, b interface{}) (int, error) {
        return w.Write(b.([]byte))
    }, []interface{}{bs...}) // it also can't be compiled
}
type writeFunc func(int, interface{}) (int, error)

func writeV(fn writeFunc, slice []interface{}) (n int, err error) {
    var m int
    for index, s := range slice {
        if m, err = fn(index, s); err != nil {
            break
        }
        n += m
    )
    return
}
```

I thought `interface{}` can represent any type, so `[]interface` can also represent any `[]type` before, now I know I'm wrong, `[]type` is a whole type, can't be considered as `[]interface{}`.

So, can anyone help me how to make this code work, or any other solution?

**PS**: I know that `[]byte` or `string` can be converted to one another, but it's not actually my intention, may be there is another type rather than `[]byte` and `string`.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

> now I know I'm wrong, `[]type` is a whole type, can't be considered as `[]interface{}`.

Yes, and that is because `interface{}` is its own type (and not an "alias" for any other type).
As I mention in "[what is the meaning of `interface{}` in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23148998/6309)" (if `v` is a `interface{}` variable):

> Beginner gophers are led to believe that “`v` is of any type”, but that is wrong.
> `v` is not of any type; it is of `interface{}` type.

The [FAQ mentions](https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface)

> **they do not have the same representation in memory**.
>
> It is necessary to **copy the elements individually to the destination slice**.
> This example converts a slice of int to a slice of `interface{}`:

```
t := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
s := make([]interface{}, len(t))
for i, v := range t {
    s[i] = v
}
```

---

[Tom L](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12817546/tom-l) propose [this example](https://play.golang.org/p/pbNQ1M3feGE) (in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27689058/convert-string-to-interface/27689178#comment107099161_27689178)):

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    x := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d"}
    fmt.Printf("%T: %v\n", x, x)

    //converting a []string to a []interface{}
    y := make([]interface{}, len(x))
    for i, v := range x {
        y[i] = v
    }
    fmt.Printf("%T: %v\n", y, y)

    //converting a []interface{} to a []string
    z := make([]string, len(y))
    for i, v := range y {
        z[i] = fmt.Sprint(v)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%T: %v\n", z, z)

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and i have another question is that can `[]interface{slice...}` be work? Just like `[]interface{"aaa", "bbb"}`

Comment: @cosiner do you mean as used in a function API? I see that more as passing parameters to variadic functions: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters

Comment: @cosiner for slices, you can try the `append()` function instead: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices

Comment: thanks, may be there is no common method to convert []type to []interface{}, must define a series of functions for each type use `append`.

Comment: Yes, and you can use the new generate feature from go1.4 to do that.

Comment: Example on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/9jpvgCjIr3r) that converts a `[]string` to an `[]interface{}` and then back to a `[]string`.

Comment: @TomL Thank you. I have included your example in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @VonC Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

1. Create a utility function, like this

```golang
func ToGenericArray(arr ...interface{}) []interface{} {
    return arr
}
```

2. And use it:

```golang
func yourfunc(arr []interface{})  {
....
}

yourfunc(ToGenericArray([...]string{"a", "b", "c"}))
```

3. IMPORTANT NOTICE: the following will not work

```golang
func yourfunc(arr []interface{})  {
....
}

arr:=[...]string{"a", "b", "c"}

yourfunc(ToGenericArray(arr))
```

Comment: What woule be the equivalent for map?

Answer (score 1):

With generics, useful with sql package

```
func toAnyList[T any](input []T) []any{
    list := make([]any, len(input))
    for i, v := range input {
        list[i] = v
    }
    return list
}
```