# "..." notation in append() doesn't work for appending different type slices

Tags: go

I need an abstracted slice that contains multiple types. The most simplified code is this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type A interface{}

type X string

func main() {
    sliceA := make([]A, 0, 0)
    sliceX := []X{"x1", "x2"}
    var appendedSlice []A
    appendedSlice = append(sliceA, sliceX[0], sliceX[1])  // (1) works
    appendedSlice = append(sliceA, sliceX...)             // (2) doesn't work
    fmt.Println(appendedSlice)

}
```

In my real program, the interface A defines some functions, and X and also other types implement it.

Line (2) raises an error `cannot use sliceX (type []X) as type []A in append`.

I thought (2) is a syntax sugar for (1), but I'm probably missing something... Do I have to always add an element X into slice A one by one?

Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface

Comment: Thanks Volker, the link seems really helpful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `interface{}` and `string` are two different types.
To convert a slice from `string` to `interface{}` you will have to do it in one of the following ways:

create sliceA and initialize its size to sliceX length

```
sliceA := make([]A, len(sliceX))
for ix, item := range sliceX {
    sliceA[ix] = item
}
```

dynamically append sliceX items to appendedSlice

```
var appendedSlice []A
for ix := range sliceX {
    appendedSlice = append(appendedSlice, sliceX[ix])
}
```

Please read more here
[Convert []string to []interface{}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27689058/convert-string-to-interface)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand.