# Cannot return an array in go function that is invoked by js function. panic: ValueOf: invalid value

Tags: arrays, go, slice, webassembly

There is a gocode, which is compiled into a wasm file. I want one of the functions to return an array, but when I do so I see a `panic: ValueOf: invalid value` error. `js.ValueOf` function seems to be able to handle an array:

```
...
case []interface{}:
    a := arrayConstructor.New(len(x))
    for i, s := range x {
        a.SetIndex(i, s)
    }
    return a
...
```

but still panics, when I give it a `[]int` value.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall/js"
)

var signal = make(chan int)

func keepAlive() {
    for {
        <-signal
    }
}

func main() {
    js.Global().Set("PanicStation", js.FuncOf(PanicStation))
    keepAlive()
}

func PanicStation(this js.Value, args []js.Value) interface{} {
    arr := make([]int, 1)
    return arr
}
```

Comment: Can be helpful: for googlers ending up here, how to convert arrays to []interface{} (or map[string]interface{} with the same approach): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27689058/convert-string-to-interface

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Using `[]interface{}`

`[]int` is not the same as `[]interface{}`. If `[]interface{}` suits you, create and return that:

```
arr := make([]interface{}, 1)
```

For example, if you return this slice:

```
func PanicStation(this js.Value, args []js.Value) interface{} {
    return []interface{}{1, "two"}
}
```

Running `PanicStation()` in the JavaScript console will output:

```
> PanicStation()
> (2) [1, "two"]
```

### Returning a typed array

Documentation of [`js.ValueOf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/js/#ValueOf) details what types are supported and how they are converted:

```
| Go                     | JavaScript             |
| ---------------------- | ---------------------- |
| js.Value               | [its value]            |
| js.TypedArray          | typed array            |
| js.Func                | function               |
| nil                    | null                   |
| bool                   | boolean                |
| integers and floats    | number                 |
| string                 | string                 |
| []interface{}          | new array              |
| map[string]interface{} | new object             |
```

Note that it is possible to return a value which will be a typed array in JavaScript. For that, use [`js.TypedArray`](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/js/#TypedArray) in Go (obtained by [`js.TypedArrayOf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/js/#TypedArrayOf)). The supported types are:

> The supported types are []int8, []int16, []int32, []uint8, []uint16, []uint32, []float32 and []float64. Passing an unsupported value causes a panic.

Here's an example how to do it:

```
func PanicStation(this js.Value, args []js.Value) interface{} {
    return js.TypedArrayOf([]int32{1, 2})
}
```

This time calling `PanicStation()` from JavaScript, the output will be:

```
> PanicStation()
> Int32Array(2) [1, 2]
```

Comment: Excellent, thank You. I initially tried to return 2d arrays, so `js.TypedArrayOf()` wasn't really helpfull.