# Nil slice vs empty slice and nil value comparison

Tags: go

I have read some text regarding nil slice vs empty slice. I believe I have some basic understanding of the differences between them.

Summary of my understanding: `var instance []Type` is nil slice and `instance == nil` returns `true`; while `instance:=[]Type{}` is empty slice and `instance != nil`

However this particular instance still puzzles me.

Please look at the link below for code. My question is the last 2 cases.
https://play.golang.org/p/udyHoOlSeP

Suppose I want to compare two slices, renamed type and interface matching and all. The instance where a receiver can be `nil`, even though it's not defined as copy by value; while the argument is copied by value, seems to 
be non-nil as long as the argument is not untyped.

In the last 2 cases, receiver has been identified as `nil` while argument is being processed by `:=` so it becomes an empty slice. (But the `other == nil` also reports false...) How can I fix this to satisfy the following requirement?

`nilslice.Equals(nilslice) // -> true`

---

Further, I tried to define another interface comparing to pointers of interface but failed. Compiler complains that

`cannot use p (type *AnotherNullable) as type *PointerComparable in argument to AnotherNullable(nil).Equals:
    *PointerComparable is pointer to interface, not interface`
https://play.golang.org/p/wYO1GKcBds

How can I fix that?

EDIT: Thanks to @zippoxer for all the insights. I learned a lot. I hope new readers too, please don't forget to check out @zippoxer's comment in the answer too!

Comment: I updated my answer to address your first question too :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you don't need a pointer to an interface. An interface is already a pointer. 
See [Go: What's the meaning of interface{}?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23148812/go-whats-the-meaning-of-interface/23148998#23148998)

Just change the Equals method to accept a `PointerComparable` instead of a `*PointerComparable`. Equals will accept an interface instead of a pointer to an interface, but you can still pass a pointer to a slice/whatever to it.
See https://play.golang.org/p/e_Gtq2oAFA

Second, the receiver `Nullable` isn't an interface, while the argument you pass to Equals is an interface. That would explain why the `Nullable` receiver stays nil and the `Comparable` argument isn't nil although it's underlying slice is. The thing is, the `Comparable` argument is an interface that points to something, so whatever it points to, it won't be nil.

This code explains the problem:

```
var a interface{}
fmt.Println(a == nil) // true, the interface doesn't point to anything
var someNilSlice []int
fmt.Println(someNilSlice == nil) // true, just some nil slice
a = someNilSlice
fmt.Println(a == nil) // false, now the interface does point to something
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That clarifies plenty. Can you advice what would you do if you were to fulfill `nilslice.Equals(nilslice) -> true`, not attempting to be somewhat generic and go for concrete implementation everytime?

Comment: I'd compare both slices by length first. If `len(a)==len(b)`, they would both be empty or nil slices. If you must know whether the interface argument is nil and not just empty, try casting it back to the slice that it is, then compare. For example, `other.(Nullable) == nil`.

Comment: @nilbot You're digging deep into Go's type system. If I'm to be honest, I never thought of these issues until you brought them up, so nice digging ;-)