# Do we have something same as Java and C# Object in Golang?

Tags: go

In Java and C#, the `Object` class is implicitly parent of all classes that are defined. Is there something similar in go?

Comment: Go types don't even have parents, let alone a common ancestor.

Comment: There are no classes in go. What specific problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: In java there are some default implementation for methods like `getHashCode` or `toString`. What happens to them in golang?

Comment: there is Stringer interface instead of toString:  https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interface_conversions

Comment: for better help please provide use cases in new questions with  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**There is no inheritance in Go.**
I think you are looking for `interface`: [Go: What's the meaning of interface{}?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23148812/go-whats-the-meaning-of-interface)

but if you need something similar to Object (not Class) you may use `interface`:

> Variables of interface type also have a distinct dynamic type, which
>   is the concrete type of the value assigned to the variable at run time
>   (unless the value is the predeclared identifier nil, which has no
>   type). The dynamic type may vary during execution but values stored in
>   interface variables are always assignable to the static type of the
>   variable.
>
> ```
> var x interface{}  // x is nil and has static type interface{}
> var v *T           // v has value nil, static type *T
> x = 42             // x has value 42 and dynamic type int
> x = v              // x has value (*T)(nil) and dynamic type *T
> ```

and:

Interface types:

> An interface type specifies a method set called its interface. A
>   variable of interface type can store a value of any type with a method
>   set that is any superset of the interface. Such a type is said to
>   implement the interface. The value of an uninitialized variable of
>   interface type is nil.

see:  http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html

Comment: It's inaccurate to say that go isn't an OOP language. It has objects (of any user-defined type) and methods, just not inheritance. But inheritance is not a defining property of OO languages -- see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming

Comment: ACK. I always say that Go is object-oriented, but not class-based.