# How to get keys of map

Tags: generics, go, go-reflect

I have a function named `Keys()` to get all the keys of a map, here is the code:

```golang
func main() {
    m2 := map[int]interface{}{
        2:"string",
        3:"int",
    }
    fmt.Println(Keys(m2))
}
func Keys(m map[interface{}]interface{}) (keys []interface{}) {
    for k := range m {
        keys = append(keys, k)
    }
    return keys
}
```

But I got

```
cannot use m2 (type map[int]interface {}) as type map[interface {}]interface {} in argument to Keys
```

Does Go support generics and how should I fix my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1- Golang is strongly typed language, So the `map[int]interface{}` is not compatible with `map[interface{}]interface{}`.
`int` is different type than `interface{}`, 
and see: [Go: What's the meaning of interface{}?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23148812/go-whats-the-meaning-of-interface)

2- No, Golang doesn't support generics, and this is very good, because it makes language simple and fast.

---

You have some options:

If you don't want to change the type of map used:
1- You may edit the function to: `func Keys(m map[int]interface{}) []int`, like this working sample code:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    m2 := map[int]interface{}{
        2: "string",
        3: "int",
    }
    fmt.Println(Keys(m2))
}

func Keys(m map[int]interface{}) []int {
    keys := make([]int, len(m))
    i := 0
    for k := range m {
        keys[i] = k
        i++
    }
    return keys
}
```

output ( may not be in order):

```
[2 3]
```

---

2- Or you may edit the function to: `func Keys(m map[int]interface{}) []interface{}`, like this working sample code:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    m2 := map[int]interface{}{
        2: "string",
        3: "int",
    }
    fmt.Println(Keys(m2))
}

func Keys(m map[int]interface{}) []interface{} {
    keys := make([]interface{}, len(m))
    i := 0
    for k := range m {
        keys[i] = k
        i++
    }
    return keys
}
```

output ( may not be in order):

```
[2 3]
```

---

If you don't want to change the `Keys` function used:
3- You may edit the map to: `map[interface{}]interface{}`, like this working sample code:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    m2 := map[interface{}]interface{}{
        2: "string",
        3: "int",
    }
    fmt.Println(Keys(m2))
}

func Keys(m map[interface{}]interface{}) []interface{} {
    keys := make([]interface{}, len(m))
    i := 0
    for k := range m {
        keys[i] = k
        i++
    }
    return keys
}
```

---

4- Also you may use `reflect` package for some use cases, but with the performance (speed) penalty.
And See: [The Laws of Reflection](https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection)

Answer (score 6):

Besides Amd's solution, you can also make use of the reflect library if you do not want to change the type of map used.

```
func main() {
    m2 := map[int]interface{}{
        2: "string",
        3: "int",
    }

    k := Keys(m2)

    fmt.Printf("Keys: %v\n", k)
}

func Keys(m interface{}) (keys []interface{}) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(m)
    if v.Kind() != reflect.Map {
        fmt.Errorf("input type not a map: %v", v)
    }

    for _, k := range v.MapKeys() {
        keys = append(keys, k.Interface())
    }
    return keys

}
```

Note that if you use this solution, the returned keys from `Keys` will contain each key value wrapped in an interface itself. So to get the actual value you might have to do type assertions:

```
k := Keys(m2)
k1 := k[0].(int) // k[0] is an interface value, k1 is an int
```

[Working Code](https://play.golang.org/p/jEHBDotIG3).

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Go 1.18 (released in beta) the language adds type parameters and you are be able to easily write a function like this:

```
func Keys[K comparable, V any](m map[K]V) []K {
    keys := make([]K, 0, len(m))
    for k := range m {
        keys = append(keys, k)
    }
    return keys
}
```

Example usage:

```
func main() {
    m := map[int]string{2: "string", 3: "int"}
    keys := Keys(m)
    fmt.Println(keys)                 // [2 3]
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(keys)) // []int

    m2 := map[string]int{"a": 1, "b": 2}
    keys2 := Keys(m2)
    fmt.Println(keys2)                 // [a b]
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(keys2)) // []string
}
```

Playground: https://gotipplay.golang.org/p/pdsI2H7w-N4

Note that, based on the [current proposal](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/43651-type-parameters.md#map-keys), the type constraint on the type parameter `K` is the predeclared identifier `comparable`, instead of `any`.

This is because map keys must support [comparison operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types). Therefore you must restrict `K` to comparable types only.

---

Alternatively based on [this accepted proposal](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/47649) the new package `maps` is also available to accomplish the same thing. However this is not yet in the standard library. Instead it was included in [`golang.org/x/exp`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/exp/+/master:maps/maps.go), therefore it is **not covered by Go 1 compatibility promise**.

The difference between `maps.Keys` and the function above is that `maps.Keys` is parametrized on `M` (other than `K` and `V`), with the approximate constraint `~map[K]V`. This allows all defined types with underlying `map`:

```
type MyMap map[string]int
```

The usage is basically the same:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"

    "golang.org/x/exp/maps"
)

func main() {
    m := map[int]string{2: "string", 3: "int"}
    keys := maps.Keys(m)
    fmt.Println(keys)                 // [2 3]
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(keys)) // []int
}
```

Playground: https://gotipplay.golang.org/p/Bx11jmyifAg