# How to decode JSON based on object type in Golang

Tags: json, go, struct, stream, unmarshalling

If you have the following JSON structure:

```
[
  {
    "type": "home",
    "name": "house #1",
    ... some number of properties for home #1
  },
  {
    "type": "bike",
    "name": "trek bike #1",
    ... some number of properties for bike #1
  },
  {
    "type": "home",
    "name": "house #2",
    ... some number of properties for home #2
  }
]
```

How do you decode this in Golang to a struct without knowing what each type is until you unmarshall the object. It seems like you would have to do this unmarshalling twice.

Also from what I can tell, I should probably be using the RawMessage to delay the decoding.  But I am not sure how this would look.

Say I had the following structs:

```
type HomeType struct {
  Name                  string       `json:"name,omitempty"`
  Description           string       `json:"description,omitempty"`
  Bathrooms             string       `json:"bathrooms,omitempty"`
  ... more properties that are unique to a home
}

type BikeType struct {
  Name                  string       `json:"name,omitempty"`
  Description           string       `json:"description,omitempty"`
  Tires                 string       `json:"tires,omitempty"`
  ... more properties that are unique to a bike
}
```

Second question.  Is it possible to do this in streaming mode? For when this array is really large?

Thanks

Comment: If there's a "type" field, and all the attributes are strings, why not just unmarshal into `[]map[string]string`?

Comment: Imagine the JSON objects having lots of properties including sub-objects and arrays of objects.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to manipulate the objects you will have to know what type they are.
But if you only want to pass them over, for example:
If you get from DB some big object only to [Marshal](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) it and pass it to client side, 
you can use an empty `interface{}` type:

```
type HomeType struct {
  Name                  interface{}        `json:"name,omitempty"`
  Description           interface{}        `json:"description,omitempty"`
  Bathrooms             interface{}        `json:"bathrooms,omitempty"`
  ... more properties that are unique to a home
}

type BikeType struct {
  Name                  interface{}        `json:"name,omitempty"`
  Description           interface{}        `json:"description,omitempty"`
  Tires                 interface{}        `json:"tires,omitempty"`
  ... more properties that are unique to a bike
}
```

Read here for more about empty interfaces - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23148812/go-whats-the-meaning-of-interface)

Hope this is what you ment