# What does piece of code do in golang?

Tags: go

I tried to search this and figure out exactly how it work but I'm having trouble finding an explanation.

If i have a variable `data` of type `interface{}` (`data interface{}`)

What would `eventData := data.(map[string]interface{})` be doing? I know interface can represent a number of things, but what is a high level overview of what his happening here?

Comment: It asserts that the concrete value stored in `data` is of type `map[string]interface{}`, and "extracts" this value and stores it in `eventData` (which will have a static type of `map[string]interface{}`.

Comment: You can find more useful information about `interface{}` type here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23148812/go-whats-the-meaning-of-interface

Comment: Thanks for the explanations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a type assertion:

> A type assertion provides access to an interface value's underlying concrete value.

`t := i.(T)`

https://tour.golang.org/methods/15

If the asserion does not hold it will trigger a panic. To test if the value is of specific type T you can use this:

`t, ok := i.(T)`

Ok is a boolean that is `true` if the assertion holds and `false` otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation I really appreciate it! Makes perfect sense now.