# How to retrieve nested map data "json.unmarshal()" as empty interface

Tags: json, string, dictionary, go, marshalling

This seems to be an easy question, but I haven't figured out how to do it: I have a nested map item, which when printed out is like the following:

```
fmt.Println("s3Info:", s3Info)
```

printout:

```
s3Info: [[map[s3Config:map[bucket:testbucket-data s3Key:runs/6033fd684304200011ef3bc5/init/03a78d21-446a-41bc-b4c1-eb66e04f45e2/52c8a076-f6c4-4180-8625-38ca52482628] size:158971 type:s3 varType:File]]
```

I wonder how can I get the value of `bucket` and `s3Key` from the object `s3Info`?

I tried to use `s3Info.s3Config` to access `s3Config`, but then got the following error:

```
go/api_default_service_data_item.go:659:46: s3Info.s3Config undefined (type interface {} is interface with no methods)
```

I also tried to use `s3Info["s3Config"]` to access `s3Config`, but then got the following error:

```
go/api_default_service_data_item.go:660:46: invalid operation: s3Info["s3Config"] (type interface {} does not support indexing)
```

**ADDED:**
The code is part of a program which processes the query response from an API endpoint, the following is the code:

```
var runData map[string]interface{}

json.Unmarshal(body, &runData)

p := runData["p"].(map[string]interface{})
init := p["init"].(map[string]interface{})
outputs := init["outputs"].(map[string]interface{})
for key, s3Info := range outputs {
    // printout s3Info
    fmt.Println("s3Info:", s3Info)
    // check type
    switch c := s3Info.(type) {
        case string:
            fmt.Println("Key:", key, "=>", "s3Info:", s3Info)
        default:
            fmt.Printf("s3Info Type: %T\n", c)
    }
    // type assert to map
    s3Info := outputs[key].(map[string]interface{})
    fmt.Println("Key:", key, "=>", "s3Config:", s3Info["s3Config"])
}
```

The printout is as follows:

```
s3Info: [map[s3Config:map[bucket:testbucket-data s3Key:runs/6033fd684304200011ef3bc5/init/03a78d21-446a-41bc-b4c1-eb66e04f45e2/52c8a076-f6c4-4180-8625-38ca52482628] size:158971 type:s3 varType:File]]
s3Info Type: []interface {}
interface conversion: interface {} is []interface {}, not map[string]interface {}
```

Comment: `.` is for accessing struct fields, you don't have a struct, you have a map. Here's the relevant section of the Tour: https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/19

Comment: Hi @Adrian, I tried that already, also failed, please check my new edited question.

Comment: s3Info is an [empty interface](https://tour.golang.org/methods/14) so will need to use [type assertion](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15) (or [reflection](https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection)). Where is this data coming from? (Empty interfaces have their uses but should [probably be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65717537/11810946) unless there is a real need to use one)

Comment: `s3Info` is the data I got from another API service, do I need to assert it to a struct in order to use it?

Comment: I tried to map it to a struct, but then got this error `interface conversion: interface {} is string, not widgets.S3Info`.

Comment: I would look at how you are retrieving the info from the other service; it looks like it's returning a string rather than the `widgets.S3Info` you are expecting (another reason to avoid `interface{}`!). See the [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/T_w2YctB1bA) for a quick example of how this error occurs.

Comment: @brits You seems to be right, looks like `s3Info`  is a string rather than a map. Is it possible to change it to a map, so that I can modify it's content? (I would like to add new  key-value pairs to it)

Comment: Changing it to a map would require parsing its contents (a bit of work and likely to fail if things changed). I would focus on looking into why it is a string (I believe there will be an issue in whatever is providing you with `s3Info` - returning a string, particularly in this format, does not make sense).

Comment: When I checked the type of `s3Info` (printout the `s3Info.(type)`), I found that the result is `[]interface {}`

Comment: @brits I have added the part of code and the test print-outs for your reference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229068/discussion-between-brits-and-ken-tsoi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `s3Info` was unmarshalled by `json.Unmarshal()` into an array of `interface{}` but not a map. The contents inside can be retrieved through `type assertion` to `[]interface{}`.

`s3Config` can be obtained through:

```
for _, s := range s3Info.([]interface{}) {
  s3Config := s.(map[string]interface{})["s3Config"]
}
```

Thanks @brits for the useful [link](https://blog.golang.org/json):