# Check if key exists in map storing large values

Tags: dictionary, go, go-map

To know a key `k` exist in a map `M1[k]v` is very straightforward in `Go`.

```
if v, ok := M1[k]; ok {
    // key exist
}
```

**'v'**: a value of a non-pointer type.

If `v` is large, To just check if a particular key exists using the above method is not efficient as it will load the value `v` in the memory(even if I use a blank identifier `_` in the place of `v` as per my understanding and please correct me if my understanding is wrong here).

**Is there an efficient way in which we can check if a key is present in a Map**(without reading/or the value is allocated in the memory)?

I am thinking to create a new map `M2[k]bool` to store the information and make an entry in `M2` each time I insert something in `M1`.

Comment: Use `if _, ok := M1[k]; ok { }`. If you use the blank identifier, the value will not be "loaded".

Comment: *if a particular key exists using the above method is not efficient as it will load the value v in the memory [...]*  What makes you believe that?

Comment: See [mapaccess2_fat](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/map.go#L569) and friends.  The runtime returns a pointer to the map value.  The pointed to value is only copied if used by the application.

Comment: @PenélopeStevens Thanks for the above link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `if _, ok := M1[k]; ok { }`. If you use the blank identifier, the value will not be "loaded".

Let's write benchmarks to test it:

```
var m = map[int][1_000_000]int64{
    1: {},
}

func BenchmarkNonBlank(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        if v, ok := m[1]; ok {
            if false {
                _ = v
            }
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkBlank(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        if _, ok := m[1]; ok {
            if false {
                _ = ok
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Running `go test -bench .`, the output is:

```
BenchmarkNonBlank-8         1497            763278 ns/op
BenchmarkBlank-8        97802791                12.09 ns/op
```

As you can see, using the blank identifier, the operation takes about 10 ns. When we assign the value to a non-blank identifier, it's almost 1 ms (almost a hundred thousand times slower) when the value type has a size of around 8 MB.

Comment: The behaviour is same for `sync.Map.Load()` as well?. I went through the official docs https://pkg.go.dev/sync#Map.Load and it says nothing about allocation in case we use a blank identifier.

Comment: @PrakashPandey That's a completely different story, as `sync.Map` is not generic (like the builtin map type), and hence stored values must be wrapped in `interface{}`. Also `Map.Load()` is a function call, it must return the values regardless if you use them or not. My answer shows how to benchmark it, modify my benchmark to test it yourself.

Comment: I think I got my answer. as `map` is built in and `sync. Map` is just a struct + `Map.Load()` is a normal `func` call so it will always allocative the value in the memory.  And thanks for sharing the above benchmark code.

Comment: @PrakashPandey  The call `sync.Map.Load()` copies an `interface{}`.  An `interface{}` value is two machine words.

Comment: @PenélopeStevens Thanks. If someone wants to know more about `interface{} value two machine words`, here is a nice explanation in another StackOverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23148998/4408364